# Get timestamp incl. timezone with datetime.now()

Tags: c#, datetime, timestamp, timezone

I use a software where they generate time and date for records, like:

> 20200110T091352+0100

Now I need to generate similar date format in C#

What I can figure out from the time stamp is:

- 2020 :year
- 01 :month
- 10 :day
- T091352 :?? microseconds?
- +0100 : timezone

What I got so far:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Thanks for any hints that point me in the right direction.

Comment: It seems to be a variant of [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) style dates (usually obtained with `DateTime.Now.ToString("o"))`. Interesting. Anyway, I suspect what follows T is  `HHmmss` and then the timezone info.

Comment: `T091352 :?? microseconds?` No. 09:13:52 "Time of day" `+0100 : timezone` - No. It's the offset. It's a common misconception to use it synonymically to "timezone", but actually, that's not correct.

Comment: If you're specifically interested in the offset and not assuming the local setting, use `DateTimeOffset`... `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmsszzzz")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 20200110T091352+0100

This is the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) *Basic Format* for a "complete representation" with offset.  It is defined in ISO 8601:2004(E) section 4.3.2.

It may look odd, because often when people talk about ISO 8601, they mean the *Extended Format*, which for your example would be `2020-01-10T09:13:52+01:00`.  Both formats (and others) are part of the ISO 8601 specification.

The `T091352` represents the time of day, 09:13:52.  The `+0100` indicates the time zone offset for that local time.  In other words, 09:13:52 was 1 hour ahead of UTC (which would be 08:13:52 for that same moment in time).

You can best get the current time in this format from .NET as follows:

```
DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
string formatted = now.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmsszzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Remove(18,1);
```

[Working .NET Fiddle here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZxbUVz)

The `.Remove(18,1)` takes the colon (`:`) out of the offset string produced by the `zzz` format specified.  Unfortunately, .NET doesn't have a format specifier for an offset showing both hours and minutes that doesn't include the colon.  You could get the same results with `.Replace(":","")` if you prefer.

Also note that I used `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`, because you want the offset to always show in the response correctly.  `zzz` isn't recommended for `DateTime` values per [the notes in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#zzzSpecifier), and while `K` would work for `DateTime.Now`, it wouldn't necessarily be consistent for other values because it depends on the `.Kind` property.  If you must use `DateTime`, use `K` rather than `zzz`, but check the `.Kind` carefully.

Comment: `+1` We, as programmers, sometimes forget that ISO 8601 standart _might_ have more than one formats. And using `.Remove(18,1)` as like a magical number, as you mentioned, programmers don't like this kind string manipulations but in this case looks like we don't have much option  `(: `